# A Constructor for Incremental Loading Collection Helpers in UWP C#

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

How can I add a constructor to my `IncrementalLoadingCollection`. I want to add a constructor to pass arguments to the `GetPagedItemsAsync` method to load data from an API.

My Incremental Loading Collection:

```cs
public class PeopleSource : IIncrementalSource<Person>
{
    private readonly List<Person> people;

    public PeopleSource(int maxValue)
    {
        // Creates an example collection.
        people = new List<Person>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= maxValue; i++)
        {
            var p = new Person { Name = "Person " + i };
            people.Add(p);
        }
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        // Gets items from the collection according to pageIndex and pageSize parameters.
        var result = (from p in people
                        select p).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        // Simulates a longer request...
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The above code is an example from Microsoft. There is a constructor for `People` which takes an Argument named `maxValue`.

```cs
var collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<PeopleSource, Person>();
```

The above code is an Initialization of the Incremental Loading class. But where do I pass on the `maxValue` Argument?? Please Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't make much sense because functions/methods and constructors are fundamentally different things.

`GetPagedItemsAsync` is a function that returns a value (a `Task<IEnumerable<Person>>`). Constructors only ever return new instances of objects; in this case, a new instance of `PeopleSource`.

You cannot create a `PeopleSource` constructor that takes `int maxSource` and have it return a `Task<IEnumerable<Person>>`.

EDIT:

As an alternative, you could create a method that creates a new `PeopleSource`, then executes the `GetPagedItemsAsync` method.

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int maxValue, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var instance = new PeopleSource(maxValue);
    return instance.GetPagedItemsAsync(pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

Note that this is less than optimal, because if you have to invoke `GetPagedItemsAsync` multiple times, it will repopulate the `PeopleSource` instance every time you invoke it. This can be very expensive if the data comes from a database.

It's generally better to create the `PeopleSource`, store it in a variable, and then invoke `GetPagedItemsAsync` as many times as you need to off of the same instance.

Comment: Is there any alternative approach to this??

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a possible alternative. Others may have better ideas.